# For what values is the function integrable

Tags: integration, functions

For what values of $\alpha, \beta >0$ is the function
$$f: (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R} : x\mapsto \frac{1}{(x^\alpha + x^\beta)^2}$$
integrable?

**Attempt**
I believe there is no obstruction for the integration in the limit $x\to\infty$. So at other end $x=0$ we will need to introduce some conditions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to guarantee the integrability? A condition would be $\alpha,\beta<1$, but might their be a less strict condition? So far, I would conclude that $f$ is integrable iff $0<\alpha,\beta<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  $x\to 0^+$ then
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^\alpha + x^\beta)^2}\sim \frac{1}{x^{2\min(\alpha,\beta)}}$$
and the integral over $(0,1]$ is finite if and only if $2\min(\alpha,\beta)<1$.
If  $x\to +\infty$ then
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^\alpha + x^\beta)^2}\sim \frac{1}{x^{2\max(\alpha,\beta)}}$$
and the integral over $[1,+\infty)$ is finite if and only if $2\max(\alpha,\beta)>1$.
Hence $f$ is integrable over $(0,+\infty)$ if and only if
$$\min(\alpha,\beta)<\frac{1}{2}<\max(\alpha,\beta).$$

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Thank you very much!